# Why is my program not running? I am in eclipse ide and its not running

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package inputoutputt;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputOutput {
public static void main(String[] args)  {
Scanner user_input  = new Scanner(System.in);
String firstname;
firstname= user_input.next();
System.out.print("Enter your first name:   ");
String middlename;
middlename = user_input.next();
System.out.print("Enter your middle name, if not type NA:  ");
String lastname;
lastname = user_input.next();
System.out.print("Enter your last namme:   ");
String dateofbirth;
dateofbirth = user_input.next();
System.out.print("Enter your date of birth in the following format(mm/dd/yy):    ");
String saone;
saone = user_input.next();
System.out.print("Enter your first/primary street address:                            ");
String satwo;
satwo = user_input.next();
System.out.print("Enter yoyr second/secondary street address if you have one, if not type NA:                      ");
String city;
city = user_input.next();
System.out.print("Enter your city of residence:          ");
String zipcode;
zipcode = user_input.next();
System.out.print("Enter your zipcode:      ");
String state;
state = user_input.next();
System.out.print("Enter your state:       " );
if(firstname==null) {
    System.out.print("You have not inputted your first name, please input:        ");
}
if(lastname==null) {
    System.out.print("You have not inputted your last name, please input:        ");
}
if(dateofbirth==null) {
    System.out.print("You have not inputted your date of birth, please input:        ");
}
if(saone==null) {
    System.out.print("You have not inputted your primary street address, please input:        ");
}
if(city==null) {
    System.out.print("You have not inputted your city, please input:        ");
}
if(zipcode==null) {
    System.out.print("You have not inputted your zipcode, please input:        ");
}
if(state==null) {
    System.out.print("You have not inputted your state, please input:        ");
}
}
```

}

Im pretty sure my code is correct and there is nothing wrong but why isn't it running? I use eclipse IDE and nothing is working I've done small programs like this before and they have worked but for some reason it isn't. I made a java project then made a class and I'm pretty sure that was it unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Not running? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Hint: `Scanner.next()` won't return `null`.  Also, it won't allow you to enter an empty string.  Perhaps you should be using `nextLine`?  Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and think about it.  (It is not clear from what you written what you *intended* to do ...)

Comment: Hint 2: Output the prompt *before* reading the input from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wondering why it's not compiling, it's because you are missing a bracket at the end. If you are wondering why nothing shows up in the command line, it's because you ask for user input before asking for a username.

Before:

```
String firstname;
firstname= user_input.next();
System.out.print("Enter your first name:   ");
```

After:

```
System.out.print("Enter your first name:   ");
String firstname = user_input.next();
```

Comment: His bracket was below it. He didn't format it correctly.

Comment: Yup that is why it wasn't working thanks!